# How can I execute a query in Symfony with the Query Builder without the EntityManager?

Tags: symfony

As the title say, how can I execute a query with custom tables without the entity manager?

So for example:

> $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE x = y";
>   getQueryResultOf($query);

Sorry for the simple question but I started to use Symfony some days ago

Comment: What do you mean by without Entity Manager? Why not?

Comment: Guess you would be looking for something like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html